# Mobile broadband not connect without unplug and plug

Tags: startup, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, broadband

I have recently installed ubuntu 13.10 and I am still very new in this operating system. My problem is that when I start my computer, it detects all the wifi connections around but not my mobile broadband usb connection (huwaie).

After startup the network-manager doesn't display the mobile broadband section. The network-manager shows this section only after unplugging and then replugging my usb-modem. I don't like to unplug and then replug my device since it might ruin/loosen my USB-port. It's okay to have the modem always in, even when the laptop is shutdown.

The usb-modem should be auto-detected by ubuntu directly after startup. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you install `huwaei broadband drivers for linux`?

Comment: Please guide me how to install huwaei drivers. I have downloaded drivers from my internet providers for linux but dont know how to install it as I am have installed ubuntu just two days before.

Comment: sir i am facing the same problem i got your point to install the huawei driver but the problem is when i plug my modem the system does not open its files allows me to connect net but doesn't show the drivers file like windows does.once i accidentally opened the driver but forgot how i had opened that.help me little bit here it must show mobilepartner upside computer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Linux distributions like Ubuntu,Debian,etc detect and mount modem as a CD/DVD drive.And the network manager applet does not show the service provider name on its list.For this problem you have to follow the simple steps given below.

1.Open the terminal and move to the directory where you extracted the huwaei datacard drivers for linux.
(`I extracted the drivers to the desktop`)
[image]

2.run `sudo chmod 777 install` command to give executable permission to the file `install`.

3.run `sudo ./install`.After that the terminal shows **Install NDIS driver failed**.Skip that and press **ENTER**.

[image]
4.Finally restart your pc .

After that your network manager applet will surely detect your modem or you have to manually create a broadband connection.By,

1.Goto `Network Connections` and click on **ADD** Button.

[image]

2.Choose *Connection Type* as **Mobile Broadband**

[image]

3.Select **HUAWEI Mobile** from the dropdown list.
And proceed through the installation steps by selecting APN,etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I tried it but no success. May be I am too new to understand commands in terminal. At the moment I can only put values someone gives me in terminal and enter, otherwise i dont know whats going on in terminal. anyway thank you for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Just a hint to prevent unplug & plugin of modems,

try to restart network manager using terminal command

**sudo service network-manager restart**

& enter the password.

If nm is not at all find your modem, you may have to eject the CD within the modem from terminal or Disks.

Answer (score 0):

i was also having the same problem with the tata photon wifi max ,i was able to connect to wifi but not lan so i tried this in terminal after plugging the device in terminal and it worked but every time i have tho run this command in terminal :

sudo usb_modeswitch -W -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1f01 -M "55534243123456780000000000000a11062000000000000100000000000000" -R
try this hope this works....
if it works then you can add a new internet connection in netwrok manager as mobile broadband and follow the steps like service provider etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not for Huwaii devices, you could try the codes give in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344632/ubuntu-13-04-and-reliance-netconnect-usb-modem) thread.