# Installation procedure for Huwaei E303c dongle

Tags: usb-modem, huawei

I'd like a step-by-step procedure for installing my Huwaei Eo303c dongle in Ubuntu 12.04. I am quite new to this, and I haven't been successful in installing it despite trying out a number of methods.

Comment: see this page to install huawei modem drivers in ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/368294/mobile-broadband-not-connect-without-unplug-and-plug/368553#368553 If you got NDIS driver installation problem see this page http://askubuntu.com/questions/323031/how-to-install-ndis-driver-for-huawei-mobile-broadband-devices/368669#368669

Comment: I am not able to install it./home/drkasi/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot from 2013-11-09 20:37:45.png

Comment: what was the error you got upon running which command?

Comment: After typing /Desktop/driver$ ls, error showing as " No such file or directory". I extracted the driver folder on desktop, inspite of this also it showing as "No such file or directory".

Comment: your driver folder consists of 5 subfolders and 15 files.open the driver folder on the desktop,check the folders and files are present or not.If yes,then move to the driver directory in destop by running this command, `cd ~/Desktop/driver`.After that run `ls` command to list the files and folders present in that driver directory.

Comment: **ls** only is a command,not run

Comment: Avinash i finished and succeded all steps and also followed NDIS drivers also but  i am not able to see mobile partner in network connections.

Comment: restart your pc,after done all the steps

Comment: if there is any problem,post it here.

Comment: Ya i have restarted twice it is not working

Comment: click on the network symbol in top panel and select `edit connections`click on `add` and choose connection type as `mobile broadband` and click create,your huawei mobile broadband will detected and then proceed your installation process.

Comment: mr avinash,  its not detecting even in the panel.

Comment: see this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF8xI_DM9NY

Answer (score 0):

This article may help you [Huwawei mobile broedband](http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2012/02/huawei-mobile-broadband-dongle-not.html)

I also use a Huawei dongle, but I didn't install it.I connected it to my laptop and switched on mobile connections using Network manager on Ubuntu 12.04.
You should try my method, as it is very easy.