# Huawei e173s 3G USB dongle won't switch into modem mode

Tags: usb-modem, udev, huawei, usb-modeswitch

Output of

```
lsusb | grep Huawei
```

is

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 12d1:1c0b Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173s 3G broadband stick (modem off)
```

I've checked if **usb_modeswitch** is set up properly as per https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Huawei_E173s. It is.

Enabled **usb_modeswitch** logging. The log output is below. Seems like the device is identified by **usb_modeswitch**, and the switch message is sent, but no response. At this point I'm thinking that either there's a problem with the dongle's firmware (but it works fine under Windows), or udev can't communicate with it for whatever reason.

```
USB_ModeSwitch log from Mon Nov 25 14:38:11 2013

Using global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

Raw args from udev: /3-2:1.0

Bus ID for device not given by udev.
 Trying to determine it from kernel name (3-2:1.0) ...
Using top device dir /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.

SCSI dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2
Warning: SCSI attribute "vendor" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "model" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "rev" not readable.
----------------
USB values from sysfs:
  idVendor  12d1
  idProduct 1c0b
  manufacturer  HUAWEI
  product   HUAWEI Mobile
  serial    (null)
  bNumConfigurations    1
----------------
bNumConfigurations is 1 - don't check for active configuration
Found packed config collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
Searching entries named: /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/12d1:1c0b*
Searching overriding entries named: /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1c0b*
SCSI attributes not needed, moving on.

Extracting config 12d1:1c0b from collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
config: TargetVendor set to 12d1
config: TargetProduct set to 1c05,1c07,1c08,1c10
Driver module is "option", ID path is /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1
! matched, now switching
Command to be run:
/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -I -W -D -s 20 -c /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg -u -1   -v 12d1 -p 1c0b 2>&1

Verbose debug output of usb_modeswitch and libusb follows
(Note that some USB errors are expected in the process)
--------------------------------

Reading config file: /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg

 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 1.2.3 (C) Josua Dietze 2012
 * Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1c0b
TargetVendor=   0x12d1
TargetProduct=  not set
TargetClass=    not set
TargetProductList="1c05,1c07,1c08,1c10"

DetachStorageOnly=0
HuaweiMode=0
SierraMode=0
SonyMode=0
QisdaMode=0
GCTMode=0
KobilMode=0
SequansMode=0
MobileActionMode=0
CiscoMode=0
MessageEndpoint=  not set
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
NeedResponse=0
ResponseEndpoint= not set

InquireDevice disabled
Success check enabled, max. wait time 20 seconds
System integration mode enabled


Looking for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No devices in target mode or class found
Looking for default devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
   found matching product ID
   adding device
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Accessing device 003 on bus 003 ...
Skipping the check for the current configuration
Using first interface: 0x00
Using endpoints 0x0f (out) and 0x8f (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI
     Product: HUAWEI Mobile
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver found ("usb-storage")
 OK, driver "usb-storage" detached
Setting up communication with interface 0
Using endpoint 0x0f for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x0f ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Resetting response endpoint 0x8f
Resetting message endpoint 0x0f

Checking for mode switch (max. 20 times, once per second) ...
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1c0b
   found matching vendor ID
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 148f:2000
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 064e:e258
  searching devices, found USB ID 138a:0018
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No new devices in target mode or class found

Mode switch has failed. Bye.

fail:
--------------------------------
(end of usb_modeswitch output)

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.

All done, exiting
```

**UPDATE**. Have set various delays. Quotation from http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#trouble:

> Annother way of influencing the kernel behaviour is the parameter
>   "delay_use" of  "usb-storage" which sets the time in seconds after
>   plugging when the storage device   will actually be used (and probably
>   automounted). The default value is 5; this might  affect the switching
>   result under certain conditions. To change the default add in
>   /etc/modprobe.conf:
>
> options usb-storage delay_use=1 (or 10, or other)

With delay of 1-3, works sometimes. Sometimes doesn't.

**UPDATE 2**. After days of testing, I have an impression that it is not any particular delay setting which makes usb_modeswitch work, but **changing** this setting. Also I have a (**very tentative**) feeling that logging in/out and changing autologin settings somehow interferes with modeswitching.

Comment: see this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/368294/mobile-broadband-not-connect-without-unplug-and-plug/368553#368553

Comment: @Avinash Raj - well, it's not recognized as a "disk" either. At least, sudo fdisk -l doesn't see it. So even if the Huawei driver was the solution, I can't access it. On the other hand, (in theory) if I can switch the device to modem mode, I shouldn't even need any third party drivers. At least, that's how usb_modeswitch was supposed to work.

Comment: Try to update your kernel.

Comment: 3.11.0-13-generic. Apparently latest for Saucy?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

Download the package modemmanager0.5.1.97-0ubuntu1 from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/0.5.1.97-0ubuntu1/+build/3267777) or from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/0.5.1.97-0ubuntu1/+build/3267777/+files/modemmanager_0.5.1.97-0ubuntu1_i386.deb).

Open `Synaptic Package Manager` type in your password when required, search for the package named `modemmanager` when you find it, hit the right click on it and hit on `Mark for complete removal` and close the `Synaptic Package Manager`.

Look for the file you downloaded before and execute it (it will may be open on the `Ubuntu Software Center`), install it and close the `Ubuntu Software Center`.

Now open one more time the `Synaptic Package Manager` and search for the package named `modemmanager` again, when you find it click on it and go to the upper menu option `Package`, hit on `Lock Version` until you see a checkmark next to that option and a locker next to the package name.

Restart your system and let us now if that worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Should I disable my custom etc/modprobe.conf?

Comment: No, just try as wrote, and we'll find out what to do next if that does'nt work either

Comment: Did as suggested, except that I used a 64-bit package of the same version (the link was pointing to i386). No change.

Answer (score 0):

install dongle drivers manually.If the dongle is mounted as a storgae device then you can check whether the dongle contains the drivers itself. otherwise download it and install by just running the script.

Then in terminal type

```
cd /etc
vim modules
```

this will open up modules file with vim editor. add this lines in the end of the file.

```
usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x1c0b
```

where `12d1` and `1c0b` are the vendor id and product ids gained from lsusb command. logout and log in.connect usb dongle.

refer this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512092/how-to-set-modem-on-huawei-mobile-broadband)

Comment: Thanks but I no longer have this device around so can't test.