# Huwaei EC1260 not showing up as modem device

Tags: usb-modem

I have installed ubuntu 13.10, and have difficulty in mobile boradband. I have a Tata Photon usb stick, configured as Huawei EC 1260. It shows up in lsusb as 12d1:140b, but does not show up as device when I try to add  a mobile broadband connection. It also does not appear in network manager icon.

Comment: to install huawei modem drivers http://askubuntu.com/questions/368294/mobile-broadband-not-connect-without-unplug-and-plug/368553#368553. NDIS driver problem see this http://askubuntu.com/a/368669/202806

Comment: @ Avinash Raj - that may be a solution, but Ubuntu already has a generic mobile broadband driver which works flawlessly ONCE the device mode is switched. Somehow it's mostly Huawei/ZTE dongles which refuse to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Your dongle is supposed to switch into modem mode automatically but it doesn't. The problem is similar to mine: [Huawei e173s 3G USB dongle won't switch into modem mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381970/13-10-huawei-e173s-3g-usb-dongle-wont-switch-into-modem-mode) - except that the device is different, and so may be the exact cause.

The program which does auto-switching is usb_modeswitch. The first thing you should do is to enable usb_modeswitch logging: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#trouble (that section also suggests some common problems/solutions).

After looking at the log file, you will be able to localize the problem and cross-check with forum threads such as this: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?t=681

Unfortunately, I can't give you an exact answer to the problem as causes may vary depending on device type / firmware version / kernel version; but above should constitute a reasonable troubleshooting guide. You can follow the steps and write back.